# The problem of Spring MVC request ordering with produce directive

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a class:

```
 @PostMapping(path = "/api/v1/chat/completions", produces = {MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE})
    public Flux<String> streamCompletions(@RequestBody ChatCompletionsOptions chatCompletionsOptions) {
        log.info("Request 1");
        return null;
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/api/v1/chat/completions", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public Mono<ChatCompletions> jsonCompletions(@RequestBody ChatCompletionsOptions chatCompletionsOptions) {
        log.info("Request 2");
        return null;
    }
```

The client's request header includes Accept: application/json, text/event-stream. I want streamCompletions to be processed first. How should I configure it?

In practice, the method jsonCompletions always takes precedence.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

WebMvcConfigurer

```
@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(@NotNull ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.ignoreAcceptHeader(true);
    configurer.defaultContentTypeStrategy(webRequest -> {
        HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy headerContentNegotiationStrategy = new HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy();

        List<MediaType> mediaTypes = headerContentNegotiationStrategy.resolveMediaTypes(webRequest);

        mediaTypes.sort((o1, o2) -> {
            if (o1.equals(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)) return -1;
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        });
        return mediaTypes;
    });
}
```